# Zigbee RGB control using Xbee

Tags: led, xbee, raspberry-pi

In order to achieve this I was going to have the following setup:

**Base Station**

- Raspberry Pi
- Xbee 2mw

**Led Station**

- Xbee 2mw
- RGB LED http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/1222

**My main questions are:**

- Is it possible to use the xbee to drive the tri-color driver without needed a microcontroller, arduino or raspberrypi on the led station side?
- If I want to expand this in the future, can I add more LED and drivers combinations to be driven by the same xbee?

I'm new to this so any help or advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What does the xbee output? What does the LED driver chip require as input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Shiftbrite LED module page and xBee [datasheet](ftp://ftp1.digi.com/support/documentation/90000982_A.pdf), it would seem you can do this without a microcontroller.

The Shiftbrite LED module uses 4 lines (3 if enable always active) which are:

**Data**, **Clock**, **Latch** and **Enable** (both input and output pins, so 8 pins in total)
This means modules can be chained together easily, so you can add more Shiftbrite LED modules later on if desired.

The xBee has 8 pins which can be used as digital I/Os, and configured in "virtual wire" mode, where whatever logic level appears at the Tx input pin will be output on the corresponding Rx output pin.

So, with a bit of reading to setup the xBee for virtual wire mode, you should be able to write your code as if the LED module was connected directly to the R-Pi